# How can I investigate what caused a system failure on Parallels Virtuozzo running Windows Server 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003, virtuozzo

Sometimes, everything goes down randomly. I have no idea what causes this. Where can I look for hints?

It's the hardware node (host OS) running Parallels Virtuozzo.

I already look at Event Viewer and can sometimes see some strange events, but they are rarely helpful... is there anything else I can check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Virtuozzo the best piece of advise I can give is "Talk to them and indicate this is a level 2 or 3 issue"

We used to run Virtuozzo at {$dayjob} and ran in to several similar issues, the lower levels of support gave (obviously) scripted answers but once we reached the level 3 guys they remotely accessed our VM Host and resolved a multitude of issues we didn't even know we had.

This is of course presuming you're under support? If not, look at getting a support contract ASAP.